# Django: Ignored `quotes: none` at 38:5, invalid value

Tags: django

In my server logs, there are a couple of entries saying:

`Ignored 'quotes: none' at 38:5, invalid value`

I see the same output in the console when I run tests. Where is it coming from and how to fix it?

EDIT:

It seems this error occurs when I test code that is touching html template. It's still of no help to me, because my templates are pretty basic.

Comment: Seems to be coming from something that tries to parse CSS (like an HTML to PDF library). Check your CSS for the "quotes" property which doesn't seem to be valid.

Comment: This was it. Could you please post this comment as an answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search reveals it's a message from an HTML & CSS parser (possibly a PDF renderer) not being able to understand a CSS property. Note that it's not harmful as the property is simply ignored.

Comment: It says I can grant you the bounty in 16 hours. I'll make sure to remember. Thanks!

Comment: And I know it wasn't anything harmful. It was very annoying though :)